# DXL script that can read a module and print the AttributeDefinitionBaseType

Tags: ibm-doors

I require a DXL script that can read a module and print the AttributeDefinitionBaseType information.

Comment: What is an AttributeDefinitionBaseTyp?  If you are talking about `AttrBaseType` I suggest you have a look at the DXL manual.  Depending on what you want, you will probably start with the `for AttrType in ModuleProperties` loop (use the example given there as a starting point) and for each AttrType will evaluate its `type`, which will be the base type of the AttrType

Comment: Or perhaps you want to use a `for AttrDef in Module` loop and foreach `AttrDef`, get its `type`  and for this `type` again get its `type` which will be the base type of the attribute definition  (which again might have a base type etc.)